# how to trigger system authentication in OS X with ruby

Tags: ruby, macos

I have a CLI ruby application that eventually runs system commands that require admin authentication.  How can I force the authentication when the app first runs, so when it goes to run the command that requires authentication, it has already been entered and can continue running unsupervised?

Comment: Have you tried writing a launch script which uses [Kernel::fork](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-fork) or [Kernel::spawn](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn) to run the working script with `sudo`?

Comment: i actually ended up simply running `system 'sudo -k; sudo echo >> /dev/null 2>&1'`